# getting started with ARMCI

Tags: c, mpi

I want to use ARMCI, I try to read its documentation,
what I understand is that ARMCI is not used by developers but by a library. 
This means that there can be different implementation of ARMCI as MPI do.

Can some one please suggest me some of those implemeations.

In general, I am unable to get started with ARMCI (speaking of the coding),

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ARMCI directly, but it is a low-level interface.  Global Arrays (GA) is probably the most popular library based on ARMCI.  GA is used by NWChem, among others.

There are multiple implementations of ARMCI.  The one from Pacific Northwest can be downloaded as part of the [GA package](http://www.emsl.pnl.gov/docs/global/).  There is also an implementation of ARMCI in new versions of [MPICH2](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/) that works over MPI one-sided operations.

Comment: I will take a look at those libraries, 
thank you very much!

Comment: ARMCI-MPI has been independent of the MPICH source for a while now and has been demonstrated on a number of platforms and works with both MPICH and Open MPI.  See http://wiki.mpich.org/armci-mpi/index.php/Main_Page for details.